# How to add the input data(many data) into table below within same page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, spring-mvc

```
List<Object1> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object2> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

**ADD LIST** button is for add the code and value to the textbox as show below.
**ADD** button is to add the **all input data** into the table below.
**DELETE** button is for delete from table
**SUBMIT** button is for post to server.

So what I have trying to do is

> For button **Add** *not* Add List <- No idea for this at all!

```
function Add() {
            var url = "/root/info/add&"+$("#fieldrows").serialize();
            uField(url);
            return false;
        }

        function uField(url) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET'
                url: url,
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    try {
                        var res = eval("("+data+")");
                        if (res.success) {
                            var content="";
                            $.each(res.result, function(i, f) {
                                content+=addRow((i%2==1),f.seq,f.name,....);
                            });
                            $("#fieldrows").find("tbody").html(content);
                            bindFieldLink();
                        } else {
                            alert(res.error);
                        }
                    }catch(e) {}
                }
            });
        }
        function addRow(odd, seq,name,...) {
            var oddS = "odd";
            if (!odd) { oddS = "even"; }            
            var style="";

            var seq="<a id='field_id_"+seq+"' class='fLink' href='#'>"+label+"</a>";
            var row = "<tr class='"+oddS+"'><td class='chk'><input type='checkbox' seq='ids' value='"+seq+"' class='checkbox'></td>";
            row += "<td>"+seq+"</td>";
            row += "<td>"+rexp+"</td>";
            row +="</tr>";
            return row;
        }
```

- Call the function to call to server via ajax, not sure what is    **.serialize()** for *url*
- At server it return as JSON, I am new to this also.
- After that build html for result table. But I am not sure what is bindFieldLink().

Someone please help. I am using JAVA, Spring MVC. Thank you so much.

This post can be close.

Comment: `Can you not just give me a snippit of code?`. No, we can not. Please show us your efforts first, after we'd be happy to help!

Comment: Hi @Matthijs, I have edit my post. Can you help me? Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myJson = [{"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
          {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
          {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList.
function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);
for (var i = 0 ; i < myJson.length ; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
        var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
        if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
        row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
    }
    $(selector).append(row$);
 }
}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
// Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
// all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(myList){
   var columnSet = [];
   var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
   for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
      var rowHash = myList[i];
       for (var key in rowHash) {
          if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
              columnSet.push(key);
              headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
           }
        }
     }
    $(selector).append(headerTr$);
   return columnSet;
   }​
```

HTML:

```
 <body onLoad="buildHtmlTable('#excelDataTable')">
   <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
   </table>
 </body>​
```

Comment: Sorry , i could not understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain more in details? Thank You.

Comment: I get the error below                      

 Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'id' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document-fragment'.


Besides that, May I know how you defined myList in input data?
What is **selector**? What is headerTr$ "$" stand for?     
How to turn my input data in myJSON? TQ.